# Display navigation layered filters only on subcategory page, not on main category in Magento 1.9.3

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, attribute-set

The quick question I have is how can I display the layered navigation filters only on the subcategory page, not on the main category? Because I have 3-4 attribute sets, one for each subcategory.

```
root
 -Make-Up
  -Skin
  -Eyes
  -Lips
```

Make-up is the main category, while Skin, Eyes and Lips are subcategories. And I have created attribute sets for Skin, Eyes and Lips products.

I don't want the navigation filters to be visible under Make-Up because there are too many and looks messy, also is confusing for the customers. Instead I want the filters to be visible only if the user is on the subcategory.

Comment: if your problem get solved then you can accept answer any answer otherwise it will remain active and come up after regular interval.

Answer (score 2):

Each category has section called 'Custom Design'. From that section you can add custom layout update statements. On 'Make up' category you can add in Custom Layout Update field :

```
<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
```

This will remove Layered navigation for this category.

#### Update to keep child categories

Try this on in `Custom Layout Update field` :

```
<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
<reference name="left_first">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav.categ" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
         <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers.categ" as="state_renderers" />
     </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: Hi @Laurent, thanks for your suggestion. Is there other way to do it? Because I want to keep the subcategories which are displayed on the left sidebar and hide only the filters and attributes...

Comment: I have update my answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, I solved it using Gopal Patel method. I don't know why didn't work the first time I tried, but the second time it worked. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

just **set `is_anchor` field to NO** from

> Catalog (menu) -> Manage Categories -> Select your Category from tree -> Display Setting Tab -> is Anchor -> No

Then **Save Category**

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work because it won't show the products. The products were added in the subcategories only. For example a product was added in Skin and Foundation (where Foundation is a subcategory of Make-Up). They are not added under Make-up...

Comment: clear cache and do reindex @raduc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all sub-category products on Make-up category, it will be better if you add layered navigation section on the page. You can update the layered navigation with limited height for each attribute or can use accordion.
If you are not showing sub-category products on Make-up category then you can just select `is anchor` to `No` for make-up category as @gopal suggested.